# Web crawling with Naver client ID: Why is my ID invalid and how can I fix it?

Tags: r, web-crawler, clientid

i try to crawl some data from news using naver client id and password. however, it turns out that my client id is not valiable. can anybody solve this problem? thanks!

```r
library(httr)
news <- GET(url =  'https://openapi.naver.com/v1/search/news.json?',
           add_headers('X-Naver-Client-Id' = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                       'X-Naver-Client-Secret' = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'),
           query = list(query = 'korean characters',
                        display = 100,
                        start = 1,
                        sort = 'date'))
content(news)
```

```
$errorMessage
[1] "NID AUTH Result Invalid (1000) : Authentication failed. (인증에 실패했습니다.)"

$errorCode
[1] "024"
```

i tried to use another url and client id but it still didn't work,,

Comment: Please read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The error returned by the api is quite explicit: "NID AUTH Result Invalid (1000) : Authentication failed. (인증에 실패했습니다.)" it appears you are not using valid credentials to access the API